# Display data from MYSQL using PHP in a nice table

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to both PHP and MYSQL and I am trying to figure out how can I display the result of my query nicely in a table. I am new to both PHP and MYSQL as well as HTML.

So far I managed to create a database on my machine, created some tables, inserted some data into a table and created a PHP page that I can use to issue a query. I managed to retrieve the desired query but I have no idea how to make it look nice, in a table and also display the column names. Also I am not sure how to handle random table info as well, since my code is hardcoded for a specific table. Here is my PHP code so far.

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP MYSQL</title></head>
<body>


<form action="." method="GET">
<textarea name="query" cols="60" rows="8"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>



<?php



DEFINE('DB_USER', 'cs143');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'TEST');

$db_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "cs143", "")
OR die("could not connect to databaseaaa !!!");

mysql_select_db("TEST", $db_connection);

$query = $_GET[query];
$rs = mysql_query($query, $db_connection);

if(!$rs)
{
    die("Query failed");

}


while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) 
{
    $name = $row[0];
    $age = $row[1];
    print "$name, $age<br />";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <th>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td> 
    </th>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td> 
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Cool, so I can use HTML table to display the data. But how do I display it if my table have an arbitrary number of columns for example ?

Do I need mysql_num_fields function for that ?

Comment: of course you can use html with php.. if you have another column then use the same function, and then create a new `<td>` and `echo $row[n]`.

Comment: My problem is that this code will still be hardcoded. I have many tables and I need the user to be able to input the desired query into a textarea and get the result back from arbitrary table that have arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: well, nothing we can't do about that... we can't just have values magically appear with php.. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for. I use the following code, which fetches the number of columns and their names and displays data correctly.

```
<h2>Query result:</h2>

    <html><body><table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2><tr align="center">

<?php

    //print out first row of header fields
    $i = 0;
    while($i < mysql_num_fields($rs))
    {
        //meta holds column information (name, description, etc.)
        $meta = mysql_fetch_field($rs, $i);
        //output column names along with bold HTML tags via echo
        echo '<td><b>' . $meta->name . '</b></td>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
?>


<?php

    //print out the actual query results
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs))
    {
        echo '<tr align="center">';
        $count = count($row);
        $y = 0;
        while($y < $count)
        {
            $c_row = current($row);

            //if any value is NULL (blank), replace it with N/A
            if($c_row==NULL)
                echo '<td>N/A</td>';
            else
                echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';

            next($row);
            $y = $y + 1;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
?>
```